First column must be a domain column - Google Line chart
I am trying to draw chart in Google line chart in web app, functionality of the chart is

On loading the page Chart should display with data "All".
On drop down selection chart have to be updated with selected values.

After test deployment, I am getting the error in the browser

First column must be a domain column

Not sure where I am messing around :(
Here is my App script function
function draw_chart(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXX');
  var metrics_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var lastrow = metrics_sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastcolumn = metrics_sheet.getLastColumn();
  var values = metrics_sheet.getRange("A1:X").getValues();
  /* Find Last Index of the Non Blank cells */
  const range = metrics_sheet.getRange("A1:X"+lastrow).getValues();
  var index_values  = lastrow - range.reverse().findIndex(c=>c[0]!='');
  var temp = "A1:X"+index_values;
  var values = metrics_sheet.getRange(temp).getValues();
  var chart_dt = JSON.stringify(values); 
  Logger.log(chart_dt);
  return chart_dt;
}

Above function gives the output like
[["city","date","volume"],
["All","2022-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",492],
["All","2022-05-31T18:30:00.000Z",406],
["All","2022-06-30T18:30:00.000Z",924],
["All","2022-07-31T18:30:00.000Z",902],

["san fran","2023-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",613],
["san fran","2023-05-31T18:30:00.000Z",233],
["san fran","2023-06-30T18:30:00.000Z",593],
["san fran","2023-07-31T18:30:00.000Z",306],

["chicago","2022-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",989],
["chicago","2022-05-31T18:30:00.000Z",735],
["chicago","2022-06-30T18:30:00.000Z",497],
["chicago","2022-07-31T18:30:00.000Z",663]]

My Script for drawing and filtering the charts
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">    
      google.charts.load('current',{'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart);
         

      function drawchart(){
        window.alert('Inside Draw Chart func');
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displaychart).chart_draw();        
      }

      function get_filter_city(){                
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(filter_data).draw_linechart();             
      }       

      function filter_data(city_data){
        let city_select = document.getElementById("city").value;
    let f_city_data = city_data;        

        //Filter for regions
        if(city_select==""){
          city_select = city_data.slice(0);
        }else{          
          filterbyregion = f_city_data.filter(city_data => city_data.city === city_select);          
        }     
      }

      function displaychart(c_data1){
        var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        datatable.addColumn('string','date');
        datatable.addColumn({type:'string',role:'annotation'});        
        datatable.addColumn('number','pat');

        var rows = [];

        for(var i=0;i<c_data1.length;i++){          
          var curr_element = c_data1[i];
          var e_date = new Date(curr_element[1]);

          rows.push([e_date,curr_element[0],curr_element[2]]);
        }
        datatable.addRows(rows);                      

      //Setting Chart Options
      var options={
        title: 'Sales Volume'        
      };

      // Draw our chart passing some options
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_container'));
      chart.draw(datatable,options);
      }
      </script>

HTML code
    <select id="city">
      <option value="All">All</option>
      <option value="san fran">san fran</option>
      <option value="chicago">chicago</option>
     </select>
     <button id="srch_btn" onclick="get_filter_city()"> Search </button> 
     <div id="hell" class="chart_container"></div>


Where are you using e_date?
If you console.log(curr_element[0],typeof curr_element[0]) do you get a string as you have told the datatable you will give it?

Sorry that was an commented line in my code, I edited it. Now I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" this error also. Any help really appreciated

Thisis not valid JS: datatable.addColumn('number',id:'pat');

Would you help me with some sample codes. I passing stringfy JSON from GAS to JS script. Is that a correct way? What will be apt data format for Line chart in Google charts?

I have not used google charts. I just point our issues with your JS
